# php script don't refreshes in browser

Tags: php, session

I have the following php code:

```
<?php session_start();
....
$result=$db->query($query);
$row=$result->fetch_assoc();
$_SESSION['id']=$row['id'];
header('Location: http://www.blabla.com/successLoginPage.php');
```

php code on: successLoginPage.php

```
<?php session_start();
echo $_SESSION['id'];
```

Here is problem. When i do all things, i see nothing in successLoginPage.php, after approximately 10 minutes i refresh the page and see correct variable. I tried to clear the cache, ctrl+f5, shutdown the browser and computer, but nothing changes - still need to wait 10 minutes. This problem is exists in chrome and ie8.

How can i solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

*Edit 1:

I add logout.php page with the following code: session_start();session_destroy();unset($_SESSION); When i log in successfully and receive the proper echo, i push logout link and then log in using another account - all great.
1st question - can i log in via 1st account for the 1st time and via 2nd account for the 2nd time? Is this ok?
2nd question - when i failed to log in, there again i see freeze. If i try to log in with proper account after this, i will see old information about fail login. What i need to do?

Comment: have you tried on different machine... this is highly unlikely

Comment: On another machine working fine. I try to understand why it is not working on my computer. People, that will use my application can have the same errors

Comment: what do you use for your session back-end?

Comment: Is the code on a different computer? What happens if you restart the server?

Comment: @stillstanding - what it means 'session back-end'?
@lotsoffreetime it's web-hosting. I couldn't restart server... Or i can?

Comment: well if it works fine in another machine... then its not your code thats the problem, its the system... and no body can define a system exactly so relax.... we can't do anything if our flash banner dont work in win 98 can we? :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem.
I deleted all login files and rewrite it from scratch and all seems to work now. Don't know where bug was.

Answer (score 1):

It may be somewhat obvious but... is $row['id'] actually a number/string, not NULL? :p You could try

```
var_dump($_SESSION['id']);
```

instead of

```
echo $_SESSION['id'];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
var_dump showed Null or string(2) "13" (it is id of session). Nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried
`session_write_close();`
after setting your session variable?

Comment: this is unnecessary. session would have been committed when the script terminated at the time of redirection.

Comment: What does `ini_get('register_globals')`; return?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are not showing the entire code and in this case it is very important.

```
<?php session_start();
....
$result=$db->query($query);
$row=$result->fetch_assoc();
$_SESSION['id']=$row['id'];
header('Location: http://www.blabla.com/successLoginPage.php');
// Mystery ???
```

When you are calling header('Location: xxx'), it doesn't stop the script, so everything after your header is executed.

You could add the function die to prevent any other code to execute after the redirection.

```
<?php session_start();
....
$result=$db->query($query);
$row=$result->fetch_assoc();
$_SESSION['id']=$row['id'];
header('Location: http://www.blabla.com/successLoginPage.php');
die(); // No more code executed after this //
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I used exit() method insted of die - is it the same?